# Accessing webserver over lan with XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have set XAMPP up on a machine on my network with a static IP of 192.168.1.30.

If I go to 192.168.1.30 from a different machine on the network it loads the website that is declared first in my vhosts file. But I have lots of websites set up with entries in the vhosts file so how would you go about viewing one of these other than changing the hosts file on the other machine to point the domain alias at the .30 IP address.

All my websites are stored in subfolders in the htdocs folder. So say I have 3 websites in subfolders like so:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\website1
C:\xampp\htdocs\website2
C:\xampp\htdocs\website3
```

Is there a way so that the other computer could just go to 192.168.1.30/website1, 192.168.1.30/website2, 192.168.1.30/website3 to view the different websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up a DNS server for your LAN that could resolve the hostnames for you, and then configure all the computers on the LAN to use it (this would usually be done on your DHCP server though).